# Отказываемся от сущностей Laravel или как не нарушить принцип DRY

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

Начал писать проект на Laravel 6.2, но для работы с бд не подходит и не нравиться библиотека Еloquent. Решил писать используя Query Builder, в классах моделей появляется много дублирующего кода типа одинаковых статический **where** и **join'нов**. Для этих целей естественно предусмотрены **scope**, но насколько я понял что архитектура фреймворка позволяет ими пользоваться, только если запросы будут происходить в контролере, ну или к примеру в сервисном слое при статическом вызове модели.
Как грамотно реализовать эти самые **scope** именно в моделях фреймворка? Так как мешать бизнес логику в сервисном слое или строить запросы в контролере нету желания.

```
class SimpleModel extends Model
{

    public function getSomething())
    {
        return DB::table('simple')
                ->MultiWhere()
                .....
                ->get();
    }

    public function getSomething2()
    {
        return DB::table('simple')
                ->MultiWhere()
                .....
                ->get();
    }

    public function scopeMultiWhere($query)
    {
        return $query->where(/** */)
                    ->where(/**  */)
                    ->where(/** */);
    }
}
```

Comment: А чем не подходит и не нравится Eloquent?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, слишком много сложных запросов, большое количество записей и таблиц.

Comment: Так Eloquent - лишь инструмент, если у вас много таблиц - будет то же самое и через фасад DB. А бизнес-логика и так в моделях должна быть написана, в контроллеры пихают только новички.